# How to handle multiple Ng-models inside an select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i'm trying to have different filter models on the tableParam but it doesn't seem to work. I can put 1 ng-model fine in the select attribute but I need multiple models like this.

```
            <select class="selectpicker">
                <option value="">Clear</option>
                <option ng-model="tableParams.filter()['apple']" value='1'>Apple</option>
                <option ng-model="tableParams.filter()['banana']" value="1">Banana</option>
                <option ng-model="tableParams.filter()['mango']" value="1">Mango</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Why do you need each option to have an ngModel directive?

Comment: That's how the database is setup. It's filtering with those different models like this:

http://localhost:8000/api/test?count=10&filter[apple]=1&page=1

Comment: I think you're looking to use the ngOptions attribute (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: ngOptions has to do with the html getting back. I've tried looking but I can't seem to find how you can put a model inside an ngOptions

Comment: Either change your server to accept different parameters or you need to modify the query string manually. Forms will generate the query string based on name=value pairs ng-model wouldn't help you in this case anyway.

Comment: @MikeT, you're thinking about it wrong - there is no such thing, AFAIK, of ng-model on an option. Can you add an example in your question of what you want the input values are and what you want the output selected value be?

Comment: The database is actually expecting the different filter options in the php.

So  localhost:8000/api/test?count=10&filter[apple]=1&page=1 & 
 localhost:8000/api/test?count=10&filter[banana]=1&page=1

would have different filtered values since they're filtering on different tableParams